# ;) emote showing when using ")

Tags: php, str-replace

I run a forum site with some emotes. Code of one is `;)`. Nothing weird. To parse it, I use the command

```
$text = str_ireplace(array(";)", ";-)", "^wink^"), "<img src='/images/emotes/wink.png' style='height: 30px;width:30px; vertical-align:text-top;'>", $text);
```

(sorry, if I typed something wrong. I couldn't copy-paste right now)

Everything works great, but when I tried to give an example code:

```
function("mind");
```

I got this in return:

> function("mind"*image*);

I was wondering, why it happens. I also seen it on other webpage ([mrush.net](http://www/mrush.net)). It only happens, if you typed `")`, but only replaces `)`. The quote signs stays.

Is there any explanation to this?

Comment: The convention on this site is to keep questions and answers strictly separate; you are [encouraged to answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than editing the question to include a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're replacing inside an HTML string which you've already escaped with `htmlspecialchars` or similar, which escapes quote marks as `&quot;`. So the sequence is:

1. the user types `")`
2. the escape function escapes this as `&quot;)`
3. the substitution sees the `;)` and outputs `&quot<img...>`
4. the browser sees the `&quot` and assumes you meant `&quot;`, so displays a quote mark and an image

This is tricky, because you can't apply the substitution *before* HTML-escaping, because you want to insert actual HTML for the image.

One approach would be to use a placeholder that is unambiguous, for instance your long-form `^wink^`:

1. replace instances of `;)` with `^wink^`
2. escape HTML
3. substitute `^wink^` with `<img...>`

Comment: @Soaku Note that `;` isn't converted to `&#59;` by either `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities`, so I'm not entirely clear how your solution works; make sure you write some test cases to cover various possible inputs. I'm glad I was able to help identify the problem, though.

Comment: It's even more tricky... How do you replace ;) with ^wink^, when it would also replace ")?

Comment: @Soaku It won't if you haven't escaped the HTML yet; the order of processing is the key thing here.